# .htaccess, redirect all to bye.php, even with more slashes, with exception

Tags: htaccess, redirects, mod-rewrite

**I need**,
in `.htaccess`, redirect all behind domain, but even with more slashes and with slash or no slash at the end, but with one exception.

For example

```
example.com/all/sites/should/redirect/to/one/file/
example.com/all/sites/should/redirect/to/one/file
```

should go to

```
example.com/bye.php
```

but

```
example.com/exception
```

should work, no redirect.

**I tried**
this.

```
# Turn rewriting on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect all requests to bye.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/bye.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.png$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.jpg$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.css$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.gif$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/exception
RewriteRule .* /bye.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^exception exception.php [QSA,L]

# Slash rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R]
```

It works, but seems only for 1 slash.

```
example.com/one-slash
```

When I enter this

```
example.com/more/slashes
```

it is not working, it is redirecting here.

```
example.com/bye.php/slashes/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have two problems:

1. You don't say your `bye.php` should redirect. Right now you have it specified as a rewrite rather than a redirect.  You need to add `[L,R]` flags to it to get it to redirect.
2. You don't need your slash rules at all anymore.   Because you didn't specify "last" with the `[L]` flag, on your `bye.php` rule, the slash rules are also taking effect and causing unexpected behavior.

I think you would be fine with:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect all requests to bye.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/bye.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.png$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.jpg$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.css$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.gif$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/exception
RewriteRule .* /bye.php [L,R]

RewriteRule ^exception exception.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you.